# How can I make VueJS take note of newly added DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, vue-component, infinite-scroll

I have a legacy project that uses jQuery to achieve an infinite scroll effect on a list element. I have Vue mounting on the container element for that list. Each `li` has a `@click="showModal(params)"` attribute. When the page first loads, every link correctly triggers the vue modal component.

I'm running into issues when the jQuery infinite scroll plugin adds additional `li` elements. The links in those elements no longer trigger the modal. How can I tell Vue to take note of these new elements?

I'd really like to avoid re-doing the jQuery infinite scroll plugin in Vue if possible.

So far, I've looked at [$forceUpdate()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate) and [$mount()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount). Neither of which seem to do the trick.

**Vue Component**

```
// set up component
Vue.component('modal', {
   template: '#modal-template-id',
   props: [ 'modalContent' ]
});

// initialize Vue instance
_vm = new Vue({
   el: '#list-container-element-id',
   data: {
      modal: { visible: false, item: '' },
   },
   methods: {
      showModal(item) {
          this.modal.item = item;
          this.modal.visible = true;
      }
   }
});
```

**jQuery Plugin**

```
$('#list-id').lazyload({
   url: ajaxurl + ?action=get_more_list_items_endpoint',
   success: function(res) {
     _vm.$forceUpdate() // this does not work
     _vm.$mount(''#list-container-element-id'); // also does not work
   }
})
```

Comment: Might need more info about what the vue component does and how it relates to the items added by jQuery

Comment: Hi @daniel. What information would be helpful? It's a case of jQuery controlling the content of the list and Vue attempting to monitor the list, but fails to do so when new list items are added by jQuery.

Comment: you will create Vue instance for each `<li>` or only for their parent (should be `<ul>` or `<ol>` etc)? and what is the work flow (is it like **scroll down => the plugin add `<li>` => lazyload li content => create Vue instance**)?

Comment: You should avoid mixing jQuery/VueJS, and infinite scroll is easy to implement with VueJS

Comment: @soju: this is a legacy project. My intention was to implement this new feature in Vue to ease maintainability for the future of the project, but if I end up having to do something hacky that won't be the case. It may be best to continue to use jQuery.

Comment: You should be replacing the HTML with vue, and using data to render the LI's. Vue has no clue about external changes. It manages its own state and Virtual dom. anything added to the DOM outside of that is never going to be recognized by vue.

Comment: I'd check out this example in the Vue docs about wrapping a jQuery plugin with Vue https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I spent 30 minutes spent implementing a [jQuery modal](http://jquerymodal.com/) and that solved the issue.

Vue is cool, but there's always a right tool for the job.

Comment: This was less of "right tool for the job" and more of not understanding the tools

Comment: @Derek That's fair. I did know it was not a perfect solution to mix jQuery with Vue. Although I have done it in the past successfully. Live and learn...